# Where did these symbols come from?

Tags: notation, math-history

Where did these symbols come from? Like Pi, Fee and this weird E/sideways M and the triangle.

Comment: Ok, do you mean "Pi" $\pi$, "Phi" $\phi$, "Epsilon" $\epsilon$, and "Delta" $\Delta$?  If so, these are simply Greek letters.

Comment: "Sideways M" is such an epic name for $\Sigma$.

Comment: On this website you might find some answers: http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathsym.html

Comment: $\pi \approx 3.14 | Pie \approx \pi$ http://www.epiclol.com/cdn/pictures/2011/11/pi-pie-3.14-mind-blown-LOL.jpg

Comment: @AsafKaragila, there was a coffe shop in Berkeley called KAF$\Sigma$N$\Sigma$O, which we decided should be pronounced caf-snus-o. Actually, where I put the letter u should be a "schwa" for generic vowel

Comment: @Will: The horror. I saw a poster for some concert and one of the bands used Greek letters in a similar way for their name, I shuddered.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, you are a sensitive and vulnerable man. Women like that.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I'm wondering where the name _Iydwv Cxscujtdo_ came from.

Comment: @Limitless, it may not  be a real name, but he is listed on Area 51 as supporting a very basic site for English as a second language and one for typography, something about one for Greek. So I come to think he arrives at this question honestly, but overestimates the likely amount of help from such sites down the road.

Comment: @WillJagy, that was very informative. Thank you, Will. I was genuinely curious if it was some sort of English-approximation of a very foreign name and, in the off change it was, I did not want to be offensive. :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are Greek letters. The first two you mentioned are Pi ($\pi$) and Phi ($\phi$), respectively (note the spelling). What you refer to as "weird E/sideways M" is the capital letter Sigma ($\Sigma$), and the one that looks like a triangle is the capital letter Delta ($\Delta$). Here is a table of Greek letters and their approximate equivalents, which you may find interesting.

**Greek Alphabet**

$
\begin{array}{l|l}
\text{Name} & \text{Capital} & \text{Lowercase} & \text{Equivalent}\\
\hline
\text{Alpha*} & \text{A} & \alpha & \text{A} \\
\text{Beta} & \text{B} & \beta & \text{B, V} \\
\text{Gamma} & \Gamma & \gamma & \text{G} \\
\text{Delta} & \Delta & \delta & \text{D} \\
\text{Epsilon*} & \text{E} & \varepsilon,\,\epsilon & \text{E} \\
\text{Zeta} & \text{Z} & \zeta & \text{Z} \\
\text{Eta*} & \text{H} & \eta & \text{Ee} \\
\text{Theta} & \Theta & \theta,\,\vartheta & \text{Th} \\
\text{Iota*} & \text{I} & \iota & \text{I} \\
\text{Kappa} & \text{K} & \kappa & \text{K} \\
\text{Lambda} & \Lambda & \lambda & \text{L} \\
\text{Mu} & \text{M} & \mu & \text{M} \\
\text{Nu} & \text{N} & \nu & \text{N} \\
\text{Xi} & \Xi & \xi & \text{X, Ks} \\
\text{Omicron*} & \text{O} & o & \text{O} \\
\text{Pi} & \Pi & \pi,\,\varpi & \text{P} \\
\text{Rho} & \text{P} & \rho,\,\varrho & \text{R} \\
\text{Sigma} & \Sigma & \sigma,\,\varsigma & \text{S} \\
\text{Tau} & \text{T} & \tau & \text{T} \\
\text{Upsilon*} & \text{Y} & \upsilon & \text{U} \\
\text{Phi} & \Phi & \phi,\,\varphi & \text{F, Ph} \\
\text{Chi} & \text{X} & \chi & \text{Ch, Kh} \\
\text{Psi} & \Psi & \psi & \text{Ps} \\
\text{Omega*} & \Omega & \omega & \text{O} \\
\end{array}
$

$\text{*Indicates a vowel}$

Comment: Thanks, but how can I type them?

Comment: @IydwvCxscujtdo You can use $\LaTeX$. For example, `$\pi$` will be rendered as $\pi$, and `$\Sigma$` will be $\Sigma$. For more information , see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @IydwvCxscujtdo, non $\TeX$ applications (e.g. Microsoft Word, Google Documents) often have 'insert special character' functionality you can use for one-offs rather than having to screw around with learning/installing TeX.

Comment: @IydwvCxscujtdo If you are using Windows, you can also use the Character Map (`Start > Accessories > System Tools > Character Map`),  or by typing `Win+R` and `charmap.exe`. This will allow you to enter the characters into programs that do not have an "Insert specail character" function.

Answer (score 5):

They are mostly Greek letters that have been adopted because scientists and mathematicians ran out of letters. It also probably has to do with the first real break throughs happening in Greek culture eg. Euclid, Pythagoras, Aristotle.

Answer (score 4):

One other thing that I would like to add, is that $\Sigma$ is the symbol used in summations.  If you don't understand that, just look it up on Google.